# SQL Server - juxstaposition of verses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a database of zoos. In every zoo there are some amounts of animals, e.g. zebras, lions, elephants and penguins. I have the following tables:

- zoos: with a name, area, etc
- animals: chipID (key), species, the zoo where the animal belongs

Is there any way of making a query where the results show how many of each species lives in every zoo? Let's say that the zoos are in columns and species are in rows.

So far I have made a query counting species of animals in one zoo and then I got stuck.
Here's my code:

```
SELECT  Species,  COUNT(ID) AS "No of animals in zoo1"
FROM view1
WHERE Zoos.Name = 'Zoo1' 
GROUP BY Species;
```

Comment: Some sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: If a Zoo has 2 Echidna and non of the others have any should all the others show zero for that species

Comment: What is the relevance of "juxstaposition of verses"?

Comment: @MartinSmith - as relevant as "carnival of carnivores"

Comment: @Hogan - Well at least a zoo might contain some carnivores. I'm struggling to see what on earth this title is supposed to mean!

Comment: @MartinSmith - I agree -- I think Simon was just being poetic in the hopes this would endear good will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT zoo.name, animals.species, count(*) AS number
FROM ANIMALS
LEFT JOIN zoos ON animals.zoo_id = zoo.id
GROUP BY zoo.id, species
```

Will work fine and give you rows like this:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
|   name    |   species  |  number  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| San Diago |   Zebra    |    15    |
| San Diago |   Lion     |     2    |
| Colorado  |   Zebra    |    10    |
```

and so on

Comment: `species.zoo_id ` there is no table named species in your query

Comment: ANd is there any way of making a table where the columns are the names of the zoos and the rows are just animal species?

Comment: @Simon: You could use `PIVOT`. If you don't know what the zoo names will be ahead of time, you'll have to do it dynamically.

Comment: @Simon you would need another question if you expect to get a response to this comment

Comment: @Simon the real question is why you would need that. Once you have the data you can do whatever you want with it and display it however you'd like. An arbitrary number of columns is not very program friendly.

Answer (score 2):

something like this... need more info on your data model to be exact.

```
select zoos.name, species , count(*)
from zoos
join animals on zoos.species = animals.species and zoos.name = animal.zoo_name
group by zoos.name, species
```

or this

```
select zoo.name, species , count(*)
from zoos
join animals on zoos.name = animal.zoo_name
group by zoos.name, animals.species
```